# Javascript - Filling Combo Box with new data

Tags: javascript, ajax, select, input, combobox

I'm trying to fill a combobox ( input) with data from AJAX. This is to get every city for a selected state, that is selected on another select control (the state control).

**What I've tried:**

I'm using the "change" event on the state comboBox, when a state is selected i search for it cities and populate the city control.

```
            $("#state").on("change", function () {

            getCities($(this), $("#city"));
        });
```

That's actually working, but my real problem is: when i bring this data to the control, i have to click on it to refill it (the previous state data is still there), i wish that it would be done when i finish selecting the state on the state select input. And another problem im getting along with this one, is selecting the first option (--- SELECT CITY ---) everytime the state select input changes it cities. Here's the function code:

```
function getCities(stateControl, cityControl) {

    if (stateControl.val()) {
        var options = '<option value="0" selected="selected">--- CHOOSE CITY --- </option>';
        cityControl.html(options);
        var dataString = "state="+stateControl.val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cities.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (resposta) { 

                    for(var i=0; i < resposta.length; i++){    
                        options += '<option value="' + city[i].cod_cidade + '">' + cities[i].nome + '</option>';                                                      
                    };
                    controleCidades.html(options);
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: Please disconsider unmatching variable name, because the code was all in portuguese and i translated come variables but some i forgot. (like respostra, or cod_cidades).
The data comes right, the populating issue is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
   $("#city").find('option').remove();
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('city').options.length = 0;
```

use this before adding then it will remove all the previous options.

[see here](http://www.somacon.com/p542.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! im at work, i'll try this as soon as i can :D

Comment: @Rafael F Violato ok no problem

Comment: Well, that did not work. I think i might have explained my problem wrong.
Let me give an example: I choose Texas state. Then i have to click the state <select> to make the cities from Texas to fill the cities control.
Ok, lets say i chose Fenix TX on my cities <select>. No problem, but then i go to the state combo again and choose Tenesse but Fenix is still there and it stays selected until i go and click the cities <select> once again.

What i want: i want the cities <select> to change the selected displayed option as i change states on the state combo.

Comment: since im triggering that change on the state <select>